# Blazor Server with Azure AD B2C and API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side, azure-ad-msal

I am using Blazor Server with Azure AD B2C.

*Let me get some of the more obvious things out of the way:*

- I am using .NET 7
- I have an App Registration for the client
- I have an App Registration for the API
- The API App Registration exposes one scope
- The client App Registration has permission to the API scope and admin consent was provided
- I am able to log-in using the B2C screen and I am properly authenticated. In fact, I can see custom scopes I added to the token (yay!)
- The API and the Client are not hosted on the same address (one is https://localhost:portA and the other is https://localhost:portB) and this is how I would like them to be

I followed this Microsoft guide to be able to receive my token and pass it along to the API calls: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0

**The problem: When I call my API I receive 401 Unauthorized**

My question: What am I doing wrong? In fact there is a myriad of half-baked guides out there that did not work for me. I am starting to suspect it's something obvious...

**Here are some additional items of interest:**

API Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
// Create policy to check for the scope
options.AddPolicy("Portal.User",
    policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new ScopeRequirement("Portal.User")));
});

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

The ScopeRequirement class: (from Microsoft's github example for B2C)

```
public class ScopeRequirement: AuthorizationHandler<ScopeRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    string[] _acceptedScopes;

    public ScopeRequirement(params string[] acceptedScopes)
    {
        _acceptedScopes = acceptedScopes;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// AuthorizationHandler that will check if the scope claim has at least one of the requirement values
    /// </summary>
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                    ScopeRequirement requirement)
    {
        // If there are no scopes, do not process
        if (!context.User.Claims.Any(x => x.Type == ClaimConstants.Scope)
           && !context.User.Claims.Any(y => y.Type == ClaimConstants.Scp))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        Claim scopeClaim = context?.User?.FindFirst(ClaimConstants.Scp);

        if (scopeClaim == null)
            scopeClaim = context?.User?.FindFirst(ClaimConstants.Scope);

        if (scopeClaim != null && scopeClaim.Value.Split(' ').Intersect(requirement._acceptedScopes).Any())
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
 }
```

**Client Side:**

Program.cs (what I customized)

```
// Configuration to sign-in users with Azure AD B2C.
var configuration = builder.Configuration;
// Add authentication with Microsoft identity platform
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(configuration, "AzureAdB2C");

...

builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(
    OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.Scope.Add(options.ClientId);
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
    });

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddScoped<TokenHandler>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("api", options =>
{
    options.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration["API:BaseUri"] ?? "");
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<TokenHandler>();
builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
    .CreateClient("api"));

builder.Services.AddScoped<TokenProvider>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub().RequireAuthorization(
    new AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
    });
```

TokenHandler.cs

```
public class TokenHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;

    public TokenHandler(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) => this.accessor = accessor;

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //get the token
        var accessToken = await accessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
        //add header
        request.Headers.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        //continue down stream request
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot showing that my TokenHandler is indeed getting the token and attaching it to http requests:

[image: TokenHandler]

I have verified the URL for the API is correct. I still receive a 401 Unauthorized error back from the API:

[image: 401Error]

Here is my appsettings for the client: (Note that I removed the ClientSecret because I was receiving an error. See further down)

[image: AppSettings]

I have found that I can add the following to my client's Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(configuration, "AzureAdB2C")
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { configuration["API:Scope"] })
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

> Message contains error: 'invalid_request', error_description: 'AADB2C90146: The scope 'openid profile offline_access https://(mytenant).onmicrosoft.com/11012303-6e36-4c8a-a240-0b79d866dfb5/Portal.User 53625e8b-6d88-4061-9d47-e9821e0d744c' provided in request specifies more than one resource for an access token, which is not supported. Correlation ID: af4eef71-7c2e-473b-9fa8-3fa49726bbe2 Timestamp: 2023-05-09 02:51:42Z ', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.

If I uncomment the ClientSecret (properly format the json file) and re-run, I get the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove `options.Scope.Add(options.ClientId);` from Client Side **Program.cs** file and check whether the token has `Portal.User` [scp](https://i.imgur.com/qoESfZt.png) or not by decoding it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms).

Comment: @Sridevi - If I remove that - I receive an error on my blazor server page stating that I must provide a client secret. When I add the client secret I get the error as described on this Github link (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23284) which brings me back to having to add ```options.Scope.Add(options.ClientId);```